# how to custom datepicker actions lable?

Tags: mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale='zh-cn'>
        <DatePicker
            value={value ? dayjs(value) : null}
            ref={ref}
            {...other}
            onChange={value => {
                setOpen(!open)
                onChange(value.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
            }}
            slotProps={{
                textField: {
                    InputProps: {
                        endAdornment: <InputAdornment position='end'>
                            {value && <IconButton onClick={() => onChange(null)}><CloseIcon/></IconButton>}
                            <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}><CalendarMonthIcon/></IconButton>
                        </InputAdornment>
                    }
                },
                actionBar:{
                    actions:['clear']
                }
            }}
            open={open}
        />
    </LocalizationProvider>
```

hi,you can see i add actions for actionBar,the actions is array not object, so the clear action always display "clear" for me. but i am Chinese,so i want display "清除" only for label,how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {zhCN} from '@mui/material/locale';
import {zhCN as pickerZhCN} from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales'

const theme = createTheme({},zhCN,pickerZhCN)
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
 <App/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

i find the doc

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
jsx
import { LocalizationProvider, DatePicker, AdapterDayjs } from 'your-dependencies';

// ...

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale='zh-cn'>
    <DatePicker
        value={value ? dayjs(value) : null}
        ref={ref}
        {...other}
        onChange={value => {
            setOpen(!open)
            onChange(value.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        }}
        slotProps={{
            textField: {
                InputProps: {
                    endAdornment: <InputAdornment position='end'>
                        {value && <IconButton onClick={() => onChange(null)}><CloseIcon/></IconButton>}
                        <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}><CalendarMonthIcon/></IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                }
            },
            actionBar:{
                actions:[{
                    label: '清除',
                    value: 'clear'
                }]
            }
        }}
        open={open}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

This is good method that I'm using.

Comment: sorry,not working, mui version is 5.14.7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).